# Mysql get result of UPDATE-SET in php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have following mysql statement, is there a simple way to access `result_value`? I want to get the value that has been set in the current statement outside of query in php variable. Should I do mysql fetch array?

```
UPDATE results
SET result_value = IF('$logo_value' - result_tries < 0 OR '$logo_value' - result_tries = 0, 1, '$logo_value' - result_tries)
WHERE logo_id = '$logo_id'
AND user_id = '$user_id'
AND result_value = 0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch work only with "SELECT" query, other statements do not return rows. You can get this value by SELECTing it before eg.

```
SELECT IF('$logo_value' - result_tries < 0 OR '$logo_value' - result_tries = 0, 1, '$logo_value' - result_tries) AS result_value;
```

(or after if it is inserted)